# Doing Firebase Update that Adds a Child

Tags: javascript, firebase, updating

I'm trying to add a child node during an update. Best by example:

```
name: 'mike'
      address: '123 main street'

name: 'paul'
      address: '1189 second avenue'

name: 'ethyl'
      address: '22 appletree lane'
      pet_count: 3
```

So, "mike" goes off and gets a dog at the shelter, so I have to add his pet if he doesn't have any or increment the count if he does have one. The desired results are:

```
name: 'mike'
      address: '123 main street'
      pet_count: 1

name: 'paul'
      address: '1189 second avenue'

name: 'ethyl'
      address: '22 appletree lane'
      pet_count: 3
```

Now, if I add another pet to mike's fast-growing herd, I get...

```
name: 'mike'
      address: '123 main street'
      pet_count: 1

name: 'paul'
      address: '1189 second avenue'

name: 'ethyl'
      address: '22 appletree lane'
      pet_count: 3
```

I understand the incrementing of the count is application-specific and I'm ok with that. I'm just not seeing how to add that `pet_count` node if none is present. Any language is fine. Javascript seems neutral if you want to answer in code.

I've tried things like:

```
nameRef.child('mike').set({address: '123 main street',
                           pet_count: 1});
```

and it fires the changed event but I can't see that on the Forge. I don't think the data is persisted.

I've also tried:

```
nameRef.update({name: 'mike', {address: '123 main street',
                           pet_count: 1});
```

Those last two should have been equivalent, right?

Any hints what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you getting in Firebase for pet count after doing the things you've tried?  I can't tell from your question if the pet_count is showing up as 1 or if it's not showing up at all in firebase.  It looks like you're setting the pet_count to 1 every time.  Not sure what your increment counter looks like but instead of doing pet_count: 1, set it to the value of your counter, pet_count: Counter Value

```
nameRef.child('mike').set({name: 'mike', {address: '123 main street',
                       pet_count: CounterValue});
```

I don't know if update creates a new key if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Not showing up at all. Is this a common thing to do? Modify the "schema" on the fly?

Comment: hey, I just tried it and both of the suggestions you tried worked(update and set).  So it sounds like something else is going on with your setup, can you post the code in jsfiddle.  Maybe your nameRef is pointing to a different node.

Comment: You got it! The nameRef was pointing to a root-level node, not a child. I don't know how that happened, but I have it working now. Thx